# type hint one of preset functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, typing

I would like to pass function as argument. This function should be one of these preset functions. Have no idea how to add hints.

```py
def func1(a:int, b:int) -> int:
    pass

def func2(a:int, b:int) -> int:
    pass

def func3(a:int, b:int) -> int:
    pass
```

I would like to use one of them somewhere. For example pass one of them as callable to class init:

```py
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self,
                 calculation_function: Callable[[int, int], int] = None):
        pass
```

where `calculation_function` should be one of functions above, not just callable with int in/out. In example above I add hint with just `callable`. Another function with the same input args and output type will be okay for `callable`, but I'd like to specify certain functions as hint: `func1`, `func2`, `func3`

Is there any way to do this in python?

PS. Maybe there is a way to make this functions as classmethods and pass as hint something like 'any method of this class`

Comment: like `Calculator(func1)` ?

Comment: Your code is ok, what is the problem ?

Comment: Callable[[int, int], int]. -- here is problem. I want to get one of certain functions, not just this callable

Comment: Type hints are just that: *type* hints. They aren't used to validate specific values.

Comment: we can validate certain types for classes, maybe there is a way to validate certain function.

Comment: maybe create functions as classes with call method...

Comment: If there were a way to do this, it would be `typing.Literal[func1, func2, func3]`, but [that's invalid](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=104a5f7df8a273fae4db97a462d87d4b).